# Qual é a lógica por trás da função trunc()?

Tags: sql, oracle, funções

O que faz o `trunc()` ao certo e que outras utilidades pode ter tirando este exemplo?

[image: TABELA]
[image: EXERCICIO]
[image: RESOLUÇAO]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [`TRUNC()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm) apenas descarta a parte decimal e fica só com a parte inteira.

Neste caso não interessa ver algo como "2,75 anos". Com a função ficaria apenas "2 anos", o que é discutível porque está mais para 3 anos que 2. Então a [`ROUND()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm) pode ser mais interessante.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bem mais simples do que eu estava a espera =)) já faz sentido, obrigado

Comment: Entendo que o ROUND( ) também possa ser aplicado mas a pergunta pede para mostra há quantos anos foi editado, logo "2,75 anos" são 2 anos, se não me engano com o ROUND( ) iria resultar 3 anos

Comment: @Droopy por isso eu disse que é discutível, depende do critério